# javascript map polylines, set opacity to zero if criteria doesn't match

Tags: javascript, dictionary, d3.js, leaflet

I have the following code that currently draws polylines of across gps coordinates:

```
function update() {
    // if not today, then stick data in corner and hide

    feature.attr("transform",
        function(d) {
            if (d.day == timerCount) {
                d3.select("#monthLabel").text("Date: " + d.Date);
                lineArray1 = latlongs.slice(d.S1,d.S2);
                var polylineArray = [
                L.polyline(lineArray1, {color: 'red', opacity: 1}),
                ]
                var polylines = L.layerGroup(polylineArray);
                mappedlines = polylines.addTo(map);}});
```

What I want to do is use another function that will hide the polyline if a date has passed by (currently it leaves all poylines on the map).

I thought using something like:

```
polylineArray.style("opacity", function(d) {
    if (d.day == timerCount) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
});
```

Would work but it doesn't, any way to set the opacity to zero or delete the lines if day doesn't match timerCount?

Comment: The opacity function looks good but it seems you're applying it to a plain `Array`, it should be to a d3 `Selection`.

Comment: How would I make the array into a d3 selection?

Comment: What is `L.polyline` ?